# Calling 2 Actions from 2 different Views in the same Controller. Always the same action is called (the first in the Route config)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a Controller with the name **Pedidos** inside there are 2 methods:

```
    public ActionResult Create(string id)
    {
        //...
    }

    public ActionResult CreateEAN(string id)
    {
        //...
    }
```

When I call each method from javascript (from inside each corresponding View), always the same method is called, the one that's first in the Route config, in this case it's **CreateEAN** this is the Route config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Sesion", action = "Identificacion" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
    "Pedidos1",
    "{Pedidos}/{CreateEAN}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Pedidos",
        action = "CreateEAN",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });

    routes.MapRoute(
    "Pedidos2",
    "{Pedidos}/{Create}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Pedidos",
        action = "Create",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
}
```

Here is how I call this method from Javascript:

1)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CambioDeposito()
    {
        var sid = $("#ddlDeposito").val();
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("CreateEAN", "Pedidos")' + '/' + sid;
    }
</script>
```

2)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function CambioDeposito()
        {
            var sid = $("#ddlDeposito").val();
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "Pedidos")' + '/' + sid;
        }
</script>
```

If I change the order in Route Config then **Create** is the one that's always called.
I understand they are similar but those 2 actions have different names! why the routing is failing like this? How can I fix this so the correct method is called in each case?

Thanks!!

Comment: This looks more like a server-side language question than a client-side JS question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routing URLs are wrong because of curly brackets.

Using curly brackets in URL string makes that keyword parameter. Your only parameter is `{id}`, so you should remove other curly brackets.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Pedidos1",
    "Pedidos/CreateEAN/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Pedidos",
        action = "CreateEAN",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Pedidos2",
    "Pedidos/Create/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Pedidos",
        action = "Create",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```